# Cluster data points by distance between clusters

Tags: clustering

I have a load of point data in 3D, and I wish to cluster them like so:

- Each cluster contains points all of which are at most distance $d$ from another point in the cluster.
- All points in two distinct clusters are at least distance $d$ from each other.

The distances used are Euclidean distances.

Is this a well known clustering algorithm? If so, what is is called? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a graph in which the points are nodes and two points are connected with an edge if and only if they lie within distance $d$ of each other.  Stated in these terms, your criteria become

- Every node in a cluster of two or more nodes is connected to at least one other node in that cluster.
- No two points in any disjoint clusters can be connected to each other.

In short, you want to compute the ***connected components*** of this graph.  Linear-time algorithms are well known and simple to execute, as described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

To do this efficiently for a lot of points in 3D, you want to limit the amount of distance calculation you perform.  Data structures such as [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), or even simpler ones (such as exploiting a [lexicographic sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of the points) work well.